# Push Notification issue with OneSignal

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, onesignal

[image: Please see below image]

I am using oneSignal for push notification, Now days what is happening whenever  app is running in background and user is tapping on the notification. App delegate function didFinishLaunching method is not getting called?

Comment: welcome to SO. Please show you code so that we can take a look.

Comment: do not post text as images

Answer (score 0):

If app is open and you click on push, `didFinishLaunching` will never get called... at this time `didReceiveRemoteNotification` will get called, so implement below.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"userInfo===%@", userInfo);
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    // do here with the push
}
```

Comment: I have used everything but not getting called in any case.